# Regex on string with dots

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

```
root.single_product.baby->teenager_furn.others.
```

I want to extract each string in front of the .-sign. I have came up with this:

```
Regex.Matches("root.single_product.baby->teenager_furn.others.", @"([\w]+)");
```

This gives me the following list:

```
root
single_product
baby
teenager_furn
others
```

But I want the following instead:

```
root
single_product
baby->teenager_furn
others
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for [`Regex.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netframework-4.8) or the normal `string.Split` function.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate and how should the pattern be?

Comment: @Bryan Use the pattern `\.` for `Regex.Split` or just the character `.` for `string.Split`

Comment: @Bryan 'string [] split = myString.Split('.');'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex is matching "everything that is a word character". `->` are not word characters, so they are not matched. Your regex doesn't seem to say much about matching things *before* the dot. If you want it to stay very permissive like this, you can do one of the following:

- word characters, as well as `-` and `>`:

  ```
  [\w->]+
  ```
- everything that is not a dot:

  ```
  [^.]+
  ```

If you want a regex that strictly matches things before dots, you can do something like:

```
[^.]+(?=\.)
```

or

```
([^.]+)\.
```

and extract group 1.

Answer (score 1):

Is it important for you to use Regex? Why you not use string.Split method?   Here is example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HQgFwm

Or you can use Regex.Split  with pattern "(.)" as here https://dotnetfiddle.net/y6AGVY